# Uploading file to Azure BLOB using IoT Hub - Permissions

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm uploading files from a Raspberry Pi to Azure Blob storage using an Azure IoT hub, using [this microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-file-upload) as the basis for my C# code, and it's working fine.

Looking at the Microsoft documentation for the method [UploadToBlobAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient.uploadtoblobasync?view=azuredevicesclient-1.3.0), *"If the blob already exists, it will be overwritten."*

I'm wondering if there's any way to restrict the device's permissions to create-only in the Azure portal or via PowerShell. My concern is that should someone access the device's storage and get the device id and key they would have the means to delete or overwrite files previously uploaded by that device in the storage container.

As a work-around I *could* have a server-side process pick up files once they've been received and move them elsewhere, but if the device id/key was restricted to create-only then I wouldn't need this overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The method *UploadToBlobAsync* (assembly Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.UWP) is a wrapper of the REST API sequence calls for uploading a blob to the Azure Storage container.
The following sequence is processed:

1. REST API call to the Azure IoT Hub to obtain a reference for uploading blob, see the following screen snippet:

[image: ReferenceUploadFile]

As you can see in the above picture, the *sasToken* for this operation has been generated for read/write.

2. Once the device received the above response, the REST API PUT the blob can be called. 
   Here is my suggestion. The device can call REST API Get the metadata of the blob, see the following screen snippet:

[image: UploadFile-GET]

Based on the above result, this sequence can be either skipped or continue for actually uploading blob using the REST API PUT.

3. This is a last step of the sequence (very important). The device need to send a notification to the Azure IoT Hub with the status of the uploading sequence. The following screen snippet shows this REST API call:

[image: NotifyUploadFile]

Well, as you can see the above step #2 can decide about the skipping or overwriting the upload blob process.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed breakdown of the UploadToBlobAsync() Method. If I understand correctly, the client makes a call to Azure for a shared access token, which is then used to upload the file. That being the case, in order to secure the BLOBs against being overwritten I need a means to prevent Step 1 from issuing a token if the BLOB already exists in storage. Correct?

Comment: The Step1 is a device request to the Azure IoT Hub for starting an AMQP State Machine for uploading process notification. Each device can have max 10 state machines at the same time. The completion of the uploading process (state machine) is by Step3 or expiring TTL time (48hrs). In other words, the step 1 and step 3 must be called. The step 2 is an optional, during this step the device can check if the file already  exists. Based on the result of the step2, the notification status can be sent in the step 3 for the notification backend logic.

Comment: The issue here is that I'm not concerned about my own app overwriting files in the BLOB container, but someone else doing so if they took the device id and key from the storage on my device. As such, any solution needs to be configured in the Azure portal, rather than in application code.

Comment: This is a security issue. Your device should incorporated a TPM (Trusted Platform Module) for decrypting a device key, that's the protection on the device side (device-facing endpoint). On the other side (service-facing endpoint) is more complex, basically who has an access to the Azure IoT Hub can do it all. Anyway, if your devices are connected via MQTT protocol, I do recommend to create your private uploading process with notifications using a device twins features. It's straightforward, event driven and it can be done dynamically in the real-time.